# Style iFrame SCROLLBARS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to style, make less ugly, more inline with my general styling and more discrete, low-profile, transparent, the scrollbars that I have on my iFrames.

I can see the iFrame elements but no further embedded elements. I have access to the direct iframe styling. It does not recognize any. Basically I would like to have a thiner more transparent scrollbar. Just that.

But I can t update anything when I try to set up properties with the inspector.

Comment: Nice story, but how it's related to programming? What is your question?

Comment: please consider re-writing your question with a specific problem.

Comment: Some guys did understand it right away apparently ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found:

> The scrollbar-xxx-color property changes the color of the scrollbars. 
>   (xxx = either ***base***, ***face***, ***track***, ***arrow***, ***highlight***, ***shadow***, ***3dlight***, and
>   ***darkshadow***)

So the iframe's scrollbar color can be changed by using these into the BODY element of the page you have in your iframe. Not in the page where you add the `<iframe ...` to, but the page that loads into the iframe.

[image]

[image]

Source: http://www.tagindex.net/css/frame/scrollbar_color.html